# proto3: using definitions from other proto file without full class path

Tags: intellij-idea, proto

there are two proto files as follows,
can we use SEX enum without its full path?

DEV ENV: IDEA
Language: JAVA

```
user_info.proto
syntax = "proto3";
package "user.info"
enum SEX {
   MALE = 0;
   FEMALE = 1;
}
```

```
user.proto
syntax = "proto3"
import "user_info.proto";
package "user.people";
message people {
   user.info.SEX sex = 1; // ->>> Is there any way to use SEX without its full path?
}
```